# How to understand this phrase: a native son of Negro descent?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I came across this phrase in a paper on African American literature, and it made me wonder whether the phrase "a native son of Negro descent" could be used to describe a child who has an American father and an African mother. Does the word "native" mean that the child must be purely black or he/she can also be mixed-blood?

Comment: [This dictionary entry](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/native-son) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken without additional context, no, the word "native" does not necessarily mean either of the following:

1. the child is purely black;
2. he/she is mixed-blood.

[Native son means](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/native%20son)

> a person born in a particular place: The delegation from Iowa
> nominated a native son.

For example, a recent Guardian UK article title is [Scranton stands by native son Biden but even here enthusiasm is elusive](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2023/dec/21/scranton-joe-biden-pennsylvania-2024-election). U.S. President Joe Biden was born and raised in Scranton, Pennsylvania. He is a "native son" of Scranton. Joe Biden is white.

In the **specific context of contemporary African American literature**, "a native son of Negro descent" would most likely mean a male child who was born in the United States, and whose family heritage includes dark-skinned ancestors.

The eponymous novel **Native Son** by African American author, Richard Wright, was published in 1940. [This 1992 book review by *The New Yorker*](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/1992/07/20/the-hammer-and-the-nail) makes it clear that the native son was a black man with a black mother and black father. You can read a little more [about the native son, whose name was Bigger Thomas, here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigger_Thomas).

Note: I wrote *dark-skinned* because "Negro" can refer to people who were citizens of Haiti, which gained its independence from France in the 1700s. Alternatively, Negro could refer to African Americans whose ancestors *may* (or *might not*) have been born in Africa and brought to the Americas as slaves.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I must have used the word "native" in a wrong way before. I'm very grateful for your help.

Comment: You @YuhangMa are most welcome! Thank *you* for selecting my answer. Please feel free to give my answer an upvote as well, if you are able to do so as a new user. And of course, welcome to English Language & Usage (known as EL&U) StackExchange!

Answer (score 2):

The phrase come from a review by [Montgomery Gregory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Montgomery_Gregory) of [Jean Toomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Toomer)'s *[Cane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cane_(novel))*.

Here *native son* was probably intended to mean *American born and bred*, while *Negro descent* meant *Black*.

Gregory's intention was to identify Toomer's novel as authentic African-American literature and as a genuine expression of Southern Black experience. This was an issue as Toomer (the son of a mixed-race former slave and of a free woman of color) was sometimes described as being "racially indeterminate" and could and did at times pass as White or Black, personally trying to avoid labelling himself beyond *American*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You're right, I'm working on Jean Toomer's Cane and sometimes it makes me feel perplexed when I come across words or phrases concerning race. Your answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> "a native son of Negro descent"

**native** - born (or originating) in a given area.

> OED
>
> **III.9.a. Of a country, region, etc.: that is the place of a person's birth and early life; that is the place of origin of a plant or
> animal.**
>
> 1995 He has promoted Portuguese literature in his native country by,
> among other things, translating Fernando Pessoa..into Italian.
> *Guardian 20 October (Friday Review section) 25/1*

"a native son of Negro descent" -> "of Negro descent and born in the area stated"

It says nothing about the child's skin colour.

Comment: Now I get it, seems like "native" is related mainly to a person's birthplace, not his skin color. Thank you very much!

Comment: It would help if you accepted the answer...